# MYSQL select data from other table if given number is not between other table numbers range

Tags: mysql, sql

So, there is two tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'TEST1'),
(2, 'TEST2'),
(3, 'TEST3'),
(4, 'TEST4');

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `table1_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `range_start` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `range_end` int(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`, `table1_id`, `range_start`, `range_end`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5, 10),
(2, 1, 12, 13),
(3, 1, 18, 56),
(4, 3, 1, 2),
(5, 3, 150, 250),
(6, 4, 1, 2);

ALTER TABLE `table1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `table2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `table1`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

ALTER TABLE `table2`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;COMMIT;
```

I need a query, that would take all data from table1 if these condition are correct :

1. If there aren't any results about that table1.id in table2. Example there aren't any results about `id` = 2 in table2, so data from table1 is returned.
2. If given number aren't in range in between table2.`range_start` and table2.`range_end`. Example if we take table.`id` = 1 data, given number can not be in range from 5 to 10, from 12 to 13, from 18 to 56. So if that number is 2, table1 data is returned, if that number is 6 no data about that record is returned.

My mysql query is this :

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` A 
LEFT JOIN(SELECT `table1_id`, `range_start`, `range_end` FROM `table2`)B ON A.id = B.table1_id
WHERE *RANDOM_NUMBER* NOT BETWEEN B.`range_start` AND B.`range_end`
```

Problem is that it checks only one record in table2 (and i need to check all there is) and it returns result, event if given number is are in that range.

SQL off tables https://pastebin.com/Cft9dbWx

p.s. sorry 4 pour english

Comment: No pictures, thanks. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Added sql example.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Query

```
SELECT tb1.`name` FROM `table1` AS tb1
INNER JOIN `table2` AS tb2 ON tb2.`table1_id` != tb1.`id` AND '$random_no' NOT BETWEEN tb2.`range_start` AND tb2.`range_end`
```

just try and give feedback

Comment: returning all records, even if number is in that range

Comment: still giving the same result

Comment: SELECT tb1.`name` FROM `table1` AS tb1
INNER JOIN `table2` AS tb2 ON tb2.`table1_id` != tb1.`id` AND '$random_no' NOT BETWEEN tb2.`range_start` AND tb2.`range_end`

Comment: if possible post on sql fiddle and give the link after try this query what i left above